# RibbonGroupsPanel ... accepts only IProvideStarLayoutInfo instances?

Tags: wpf, gallery, ribbon

I am trying to use a RibbonGallery in my application, but I get this error at runtime, when the tab which contains the gallery is loaded:

> "RibbonGroupsPanel RegisterStarLayoutProvider and
>   UnregisterStarLayoutProvider accepts only IProvideStarLayoutInfo
>   instances. Parameter name: starLayoutInfoProvider"

Any idea what isn't right?

Here's the code:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1">
                        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Green" Foreground="Green" />
                            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Blue" Foreground="Blue" />
                            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Orange" Foreground="Orange" />
                        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
```

Answer (score 3):

The RibbonGallery control must be placed within a control that can take advantage of the RibbonGallery, like a RibbonSplitButton or a RibbonComboBox. Here is an example of using a gallery in a RibbonComboBox:

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox Label="1" 
                  SmallImageSource="Images/RightArrowShort_Green16.png"
                  SelectionBoxWidth="62"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  IsEditable="True" >
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="Green"
                          SelectedValuePath="Content"
                          MaxColumnCount="1">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Green" Foreground="Green" />
            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Blue" Foreground="Blue" />
            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Orange" Foreground="Orange" />
        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

XAML copied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbongallery.aspx.

If a control is derived from RibbonMenuButton then it can contain a RibbonGallery because of the HasRibbon property.

Answer (score 2):

The RibbonMenuItemsPanel-class of the System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives allows to place a RibbonGallery in a RibbonGroup. This class implements the ISupportStarLayout-interface.

Define the primitives-Namespace in the Window-element (could also be RibbonWindow):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
        xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon" 
        ... >
```

The RibbonGroup-part:

```
<RibbonGroup Header="MyRibbonGroup">
    <primitives:RibbonMenuItemsPanel Margin="0,3,0,0">
        <RibbonGallery ...>
            <RibbonGalleryCategory ...>
                ...
            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </RibbonGallery>
    </primitives:RibbonMenuItemsPanel>
</RibbonGroup>
```

Note that i use the System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon-namespace (.Net 4.5) and not the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon-namespace. But this should be nearly the same.

Comment: This is clever and interesting... unfortunately the RibbonMenuItemsPanel seems to have rather limited options, so it doesn't quite serve as an InRibbonGallery. Maybe with a custom control template...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any RibbonGroupsPanel in your xaml which leads me to thinking that you're not showing all of the relevant xaml.

In any case, it tells you that you're putting the wrong element inside RibbonGroupsPanel.RegisterStarLayoutProvider and that it accepts only types that implements IProvideStarLayoutInfo .

Comment: The ribbon gallery is inside a ribbonGroup. That's all

Comment: Ok, so anyhow there is a RibbonGroupsPanel in the visual tree of that control and that's what's messing you up. I suggest you try and Snoop the application (snoop.codeplex.com) and see the visual tree that's created and continue from there