# Microsoft Ribbon for WPF RibbonGallery Exception

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ribbon

i want to hava a RibbonGallery in my menue (like [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/media/RadRibbonBar_Features_RibbonGallery_020.png)).
This is my code:

```
<r:RibbonGroup>
    <r:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="Green" SelectedValuePath="Content" MaxColumnCount="1">
        <r:RibbonGalleryCategory>
            <r:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Green" Foreground="Green" />
            <r:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Blue" Foreground="Blue" />
            <r:RibbonGalleryItem Content="Orange" Foreground="Orange" />
        </r:RibbonGalleryCategory>
    </r:RibbonGallery>
</r:RibbonGroup>
```

And this is my Exception:

```
RibbonGroupsPanel RegisterStarLayoutProvider and UnregisterStarLayoutProvider accepts only IProvideStarLayoutInfo instances.
```

Parametername: starLayoutInfoProvider

Can you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RibbonGroupsPanel ... accepts only IProvideStarLayoutInfo instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162457/ribbongroupspanel-accepts-only-iprovidestarlayoutinfo-instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Microsoft Ribbon then doesn't look like it's possible to put the gallery directly in a RibbonGroup as you are trying to do. Your link points to the Telerik control that does allow this. With the Microsoft Ribbon can only attached a gallery to a RibbonMenuButton or one of it's sublasses. See the related question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162457/error-when-using-wpf-ribbongallery).